# MySQL UPDATE Query - Update Only Non-Duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

This query works fine. I now want to add another "rule" to it. The rule I want to add is to update `tran_term_taxonomy`.`description` with only non-duplicate records. Explained slightly differently, if an earlier record in `tran_term_taxonomy`.`description` contains the string "the cat crossed the road", then do not add "the cat crossed the road" again during the subsequent update process. How do I do this? Thanks.

```
UPDATE `tran_term_taxonomy` SET `description` = (SELECT keyword from `good_keywords` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1,1) WHERE `tran_term_taxonomy`.`taxonomy` = 'post_tag' AND `tran_term_taxonomy`.`description` = '' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` check in your subquery to determine if the `keyword` has been used before as a `description` value:

```
UPDATE `tran_term_taxonomy` 
SET `description` = (
  SELECT keyword 
  FROM `good_keywords` 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `tran_term_taxonomy`) t WHERE description = keyword)
  ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT 1
) 
WHERE `tran_term_taxonomy`.`taxonomy` = 'post_tag'
  AND `tran_term_taxonomy`.`description` = ''
LIMIT 1
```

Note that if you run out of keywords, this will update the `description` value with `NULL`. To avoid that, wrap the subquery in a `COALESCE`:

```
COALESCE((SELECT keyword ... ), '')
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e2b848d665ddd02e6bb29d865b108a2d)